# Generate a float random number with one number after decimal point

Tags: python, random

I have two float numbers where both have one number after the decimal point. I want to generate a a random float where only the first number after the decimal point count .

**Example**:

Let's say we have two numbers : 3.5 and 3.8, I want a way to generate a random number like 3.6 and 3.7, I don't want to generate numbers like 3.58 or 3.584 and so one, I want a random float number .

I can't use `random.uniform(a,b)` because it doesn't do what I want, it can generate random numbers for other numbers after decimal point (second and third number after decimal point like 3.589)

Comment: round(random.uniform(3.5, 3.8), 1)

Comment: Linked duplicate has the answer to generate the random number between two floats. Refer [*Limiting floats to two decimal points*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points) for limiting the decimal point of the randomly generated float

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not using `random.randint` on boundaries times 10 and divide afterwards?

```
>>> a=3.5
>>> b=3.8
>>> random.randint(a*10,b*10)/10
3.8
>>> random.randint(a*10,b*10)/10
3.6
```

and if you want to omit `a` and `b`:

```
random.randrange(a*10+1,b*10)/10
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
 round(random.random()*10,1)
```

Just round it to the required number of places.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why this shouldn't work for you.

```
a=3.5
b=3.8

round(random.uniform(a,b),1)
```